# Running the dummy app in an Ember addon project can't find app/styles/app.less

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-addon, ember-cli-less

I'm trying to test an `Ember addon` project by running ember server inside an addon project. This runs the dummy app. However I am not getting my less files automatically being build with the ember-cli-less functionality (expecting `/app/styles/app.less`):

Some files I have:

```
/addon-project
  /app
    /styles
      /less
      app.less
  /dist
  /assets
     dummy.js
     dummy.css
  /tests
    /dummy
```

However I am getting an error when I run ember server:

```
version: 0.1.15
Could not find watchman, falling back to NodeWatcher for file system events

Livereload server on port 35730
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:4201/
File not found: /app/styles/app.less
in any of the following include paths:
  /Users/me/github/ember-addons/header/tmp/tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-qEC1hODR.tmp
Error: File not found: /app/styles/app.less
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try moving the "app.less" file up one level (out of your less folder so that it is in the "styles" folder).

Comment: going by his layout, app.less is on the same level as the less folder, not inside it. That folder would hold partials most likely. Just wanted to clarify because I also am having the same issue as Nikos, despite having done `npm install --save-dev ember-cli-less`.